# Question-banning questions are being handled badly

Tags: discussion, post-ban

This is being asked due to this:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116429/why-am-i-getting-the-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-acco

The guidelines for automatic question banning are these:

- users who can't be bothered to form sentences
- users who don't do the most basic kinds of research themselves
- users who barely even explain what it is they are trying to do

Alright. Let's take a look at [his profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875067/perl-j). He has some good answers and questions, uses proper grammar (and edits if he notices a mistake), and questions are explained well. He clearly understands the rules, and posts across several sites on the network, including Area51.

A question ban for him makes no sense. Taking it to meta seems like a logical choice, but it was quickly downvoted and closed.

**Why was he question-banned? (I'm not asking for a link to the official post - I want individual details)**

**And more importantly, why are we dealing with question-banned users who come to meta so badly?**

Comment: One important point, deleted posts count for the ban, there is often a lot of stuff in these cases regular users can't see in the profile.

Comment: They are downvoted and closed ("treated poorly") because they *are* duplicates. The question it was closed as a duplicate of has a very detailed answer that should explain any problems.

Comment: Most users that come here to complain about their question ban already have two strikes: asking bad questions on Stack Overflow (strike 1) and opening the 10,000,000th duplicate of [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/) (strike 2).

Comment: I haven't wanted to say this on any particular user's duplicate *"Why am I banned"* question because I don't know them, but...do you think that--just maybe--part of the problem for some of these users is a pathological inability to *search before they ask*?

Comment: If waffles's post regarding that specific user answers this question, then I fail to see how this isn't a dupe of the one you're asking about.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is working perfectly here. The user has TONS of deleted heavily downvoted questions.

Move along ... nothing to see.

Comment: Seems he was a troublemaker after all. Any reason why questions aren't automatically undeleted upon question-banning?

Comment: @Santa: Why on earth would crap be re-exposed just because the user isn't allowed to make more of it?

Comment: @SantaClaus Why should they be? If a question was deleted in the first place, it was for a reason and it should remain deleted.

Comment: @Problem They don't have to come up in searches, just visible on the profile page. Would have prevented this question if I would have known he deleted so much.

Comment: I wonder if, instead, 10k users could see some indication on a user's profile of "lots of deleted posts", in some way? That might help us in cases like this, to be able to explain. Maybe?

Answer (score 5):

> **And more importantly, why are we dealing with question-banned users who come to meta so badly?**

I think that a large part of the reason such questions get closed is that there's pretty much nothing that regular users or even diamond mods can do about a question ban. The exact algorithm is secret; mods don't even have a way to *know* if a user is banned. Only a member of the dev team can meaningfully interact with a question-banned user.

Apart from following the (quite thorough and specific) advice given in the [FAQ used as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/159251), the only reasonable course of action for the user is an email directly to team@stackoverflow.com

A meta question addressing an individual user subject to the ban, while appropriate on its face, is at root useless.

Further, as Anna Lear noted below, the user has *already* been presented with the FAQ upon receiving the ban message. Absent any indication that the advice there has been read and followed, a meta question about the ban becomes worse than useless -- it is an active waste of others' time.

<sub>It seems to me that the fact that waffles's is the accepted answer to this question kind of proves my point. All I or anyone else could do was to offer general advice.</sub>

Comment: Plus, there's a link to THE meta post about what to do in case of getting banned right there in the ban message. Not following it and coming to ask "why am I getting this message" on meta instead is a sign of someone being lazy in 99% of the cases.

Comment: Nothing says "run by the community" like unilateral banning by double-diamond mods, and secret algorithms that determine when democracy has failed and the user must have his question-asking abilities revoked.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Who do you think downvotes and closes questions that lead to question banning?  It's the community.  Please stop your banner waving and come up with a better solution to the problem of floods of low-quality questions.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: That fact that you are still allowed to post here proves that you are wrong.